# Audio Thread as daemon thread

Tags: java, audio, multithreading

I'm looking to set up two threads in my puzzle game, one for logic/graphics, and one for audio. 
Am I correct in thinking that the thread that handles the audio should be set as a daemon thread, because the game can end without that thread finishing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but.

- If you exit using System.exit() then it will shut down your audio thread anyway.
- It's probably tidier to send a message to the audio thread telling it to shut down and close its streams.
- You should consider having three threads unless the logic is really simple.